# using NLTK Library for short sentances

Tags: python, nltk

We are using NLTK library.
WE are trying to chunk sentences which are not proper english sentences.
In case if sentence is proper having 'Noun verb Noun/Pronoun' it is chunking perfectly but if  sentence is  only having 'Verb Noun' then chunking is not happening properly.

A few of example is showing  below which is working fine:i am raising the ticket for my colleague for resetting the password

Example  which is  not working:reset  password  ( both lines are in in file "test.txt")

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import webtext
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer

train_text = webtext.raw("train.txt")
sample_text = webtext.raw("test.txt")
custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

def process_content():
    try:
        for i in tokenized:
           words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
           tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
           chunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<NNP>+<NN>?}"""
           chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
           chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
           chunked.draw()     

   except Exception as e:
       print(str(e))

process_content()
```

we are chunking data from text file not from some running text.

Comment: Bush talked about resetting passwords in his State of the Union address? No he didn't. Please edit your question until it makes sense. (You should also clarify that you're apparently trying to split sentences into phrases -- not detecting sentences in running text.)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: The `PunktSentenceTokenizer` is a statistical segmenter that needs to be trained on lots and lots of data. Is there some reason you're not just using the pre-trained model that's distributed with the nltk? But if your description of the problem is correct, all this has nothing to do with your question, which is about how your `RegexpParser` chunks the two sentences you cite. If so, please get rid of the irrelevant preprocessing and trim your question down to the chunking step-- and make it executable. Your question is still unclear.

Comment: I just tried and your chunker **does not** find any chunks in "i am raising the ticket for my colleague for resetting the password". So please get your facts straight and **show** us the problem.